# NuGet - get latest lib version on build

Tags: c#, nuget

I have 2 solutions:

- SolutionMyTool
- SolutionToolUsage

From SolutionMyTool there are produced NuGet packages

- MyTool 1.1.0
- MyTool 1.1.1
- MyTool ... (many, many new versions)

On SolutionToolUsage side I have dependency

```
<PackageReference Include="MyTool" Version="1.1.*" />
```

Now on each build of SolutionToolUsage I want to get the latest version of MyTool.
Is it possible?

It seems that SolutionMyTool on 1st buiod gets "latest version" of MyTool (eg. 1.1.7).
Then each next build of SolutionMyTool is using this version (1.1.7), although in the meantime there were produced newer versions of MyTool.
How can I always get the "latest"?

Thank you ;]

Comment: You may remove a package, then add it again and the latest available version will be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 2020-January NuGet behaves like here.

If `SolutionToolUsage` has dependency

```
<PackageReference Include="MyTool" Version="1.1.*" />
```

Then on 1st build is taken newest version (eg. 1.1.2) of MyTool.
Then on each next build is taken this version (1.1.2) even if newer are available in NuGet Feed.

If you need "asked flow" the simplest workaround is to manually:

- increase version of each `MyTool` with each lib build
- setting explicitly this version in `SolutionToolUsage`

Although Microsoft sometimes "recommends" uninstalling and installing again `MyTool`.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/reinstalling-and-updating-packages

> 5. Reinstalling a package during its development: Package authors often need to reinstall the same version of package they're developing
>    to test the behavior. The Install-Package command does not provide an
>    option to force a reinstall, so use Update-Package -reinstall instead.

Answer (score 1):

Just use an asterisk for the version.
The following line loads the latest version on every build.

```
<PackageReference Include="MyTool" Version="*" />
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/package-versioning#floating-version-resolutions

**EDIT**
Maybe you have also to restore the project's dependencies with

```
dotnet restore
```

The command `dotnet build` implicitly restores packages.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working as you described. Please, check my answer. Thank you anyway ;]